# Created function works in R script but not in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have created a function **getConductivity()** that calculates the conductivity of a solution with the input of 14 values (the concentration of 12 substances, the temperature and the pH). The function works fine as a script (I will still develop it further, but it works). See code and example:

```
getConductivity <- function( sodium, 
                             potassium,
                             calcium,
                             magnesium,
                             strontium,
                             barium,
                             ammonium,
                             hydrogencarbonate,
                             nitrate,
                             chlorine,
                             fluorine,
                             sulfate,
                             temperature, 
                             pH
) {

  data <-
    data.frame (
      category = c(rep("cation", 7), rep ("anion", 6)),
      concentration = c(
        sodium / 22.99,
        potassium / 39.1,
        calcium / 40.08 *2,
        magnesium / 24.305 * 2,
        strontium / 87.62 * 2,
        barium / 137.33 * 2,
        ammonium / 18.038,
        hydrogencarbonate / 61.017,
        nitrate / 61.005,
        chlorine / 35.453,
        fluorine / 19,
        sulfate / 98.058 * 2,
        2 * 1000 * (10 ^ -(2902.39/(temperature + 273.15) + 0.02379 * (temperature + 273.15) - 6.498) * (hydrogencarbonate / 61.017) / 1000) / (10 ^ -(pH))
      ),
      conductivity25meqperL = c(
        50.1,
        73.50,
        59.5,
        53.1,
        61.0,
        63.6,
        73.5,
        44.5,
        71.4,
        76.3,
        55.4,
        79.8,
        72.0
      ))

  return (if ( abs((1-(sum(data$concentration[which(data$category == "cation")]) / sum(data$concentration[which(data$category == "anion")])))*100) < 3) {
    data$conductivity25 <- round(data$concentration * data$conductivity25meqperL, 2)
    paste('The conductivity is', sum(data$conductivity25), 'uS/cm at 25 C', 'and', ((sum(data$conductivity25) + 10 ^ (-pH) * 100 * 350 + 10 ^ (-(14 - pH)) * 100 * 197)) * (1 + 0.020 * (temperature - 25)),
          'uS/cm at', temperature, 'C')
  } else print('The solution is NOT in balance. Consider adding more sodium (Na+) or chlorine (Cl-).')
  )

}
```

**Example:**

```
getConductivity(sodium =  100, potassium = 100, calcium  =  100, magnesium  =  0, strontium  =  0
barium = 0, ammonium  = 0, hydrogencarbonate  = 100, nitrate  =  100, chlorine =  1000, fluorine =  0
sulfate  =  0, temperature  =  10, pH  =  7)

[1] "The solution is NOT in balance. Consider adding more sodium (Na+) or chlorine (Cl-)."

getConductivity(sodium =  100, potassium = 100, calcium  =  100, magnesium  =  0, strontium  =  0
barium = 0, ammonium  = 0, hydrogencarbonate  = 100, nitrate  =  100, chlorine =  300, fluorine =  0
sulfate  =  0, temperature  =  10, pH  =  7)

[1] "The conductivity is 1538.5 uS/cm at 25 C and 1076.953829 uS/cm at 10 C"
```

Then I created an app.R that allows the user to input the required 14 variables, visualise the data in a plot, and get the conductivity through the function **getConductivity()**.

**Problem** The app.R allows input and it plots accordantly but it gives an error in the output of the calculation of the conductivity. >Error:missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.

I would be very grateful for the help you can give me on this.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Solution Balance"),

                fluidRow(
                    column(
                        12,
                        h5(
                            "This form determines if your solution is in balance based on input values of ions, pH and temperature."
                        ),
                        h5(
                            "This form can also be used to: calculate the conductivity or the concentration of a specific ion."
                        )
                    ),
                    column(6,
                           plotOutput("plot"),
                           textOutput("Conductivity")
                    ),
                    column(
                        3,
                        h4("Cations (mg/L)"),
                        numericInput(inputId = "sodium", "Sodium (Na+)", value = 0),
                        numericInput(inputId = "potassium", "Potassium (K+)", value = 0),
                        numericInput(inputId = "calcium", "Calcium (Ca++)", value = 0),
                        numericInput(inputId = "magnesium", "Magnesium (Mg++)", value = 0),
                        numericInput(inputId = "strontium", "Strontium (Sr++)", value = 0),
                        numericInput(inputId = "barium", "Barium (Ba++)", value = 0),
                        numericInput(
                            inputId = "ammonium",
                            "Ammonium (as NH4+ not NH4-N)",
                            value = 0
                        )
                    ),
                    column(
                        3,
                        sliderInput(
                            "pH",
                            "pH",
                            min = 5,
                            max = 9,
                            value = 7,
                            step = 0.1
                        ),
                        sliderInput(
                            "temperature",
                            "temperature",
                            min = 0,
                            max = 26,
                            value = 10,
                            round = -2
                        ),
                        h4("Anions (mg/L)"),
                        numericInput(
                            inputId = "hydrogencarbonate",
                            "Hydrogen Carbonate (HCO3-)",
                            value = 0
                        ),
                        numericInput(inputId = "nitrate", "Nitrate (NO3-)", value = 0),
                        numericInput(inputId = "chlorine", "Chlorine (Cl-)", value = 0),
                        numericInput(inputId = "fluorine", "Fluorine (F-)", value = 0),
                        numericInput(inputId = "sulfate", "Sulfate (SO4--)", value = 0)
                    )
                ))

# SERVER
server <- function(input, output) {
    info <- reactive ({
        data.frame (
            category = c(rep("cation", 7), rep ("anion", 6)),
            names = c(
                "Na+",
                "K+",
                "Ca++",
                "Mg++",
                "Sr++",
                "Ba++",
                "NH4+",
                "HCO3-",
                "NO3-",
                "Cl-",
                "F-",
                "SO4--",
                "CO3--"
            ),
            concentration = c(
                input$sodium / 22.99,
                input$potassium / 39.1,
                input$calcium / 40.08 * 2,
                input$magnesium / 24.305 * 2,
                input$strontium / 87.62 * 2,
                input$barium / 137.33 * 2,
                input$ammonium / 18.038,
                input$hydrogencarbonate / 61.017,
                input$nitrate / 61.005,
                input$chlorine / 35.453,
                input$fluorine / 19,
                input$sulfate / 98.058 * 2,
                2 * 1000 * (
                    10 ^ -(
                        2902.39 / (input$temperature + 273.15) + 0.02379 * (input$temperature + 273.15) - 6.498
                    ) * (input$hydrogencarbonate / 61.017) / 1000
                ) / (10 ^ -(input$pH))
            )
        )
    })

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(info(), aes(
            x = category,
            y = concentration,
            fill = names
        )) +
            geom_col() +
            xlab("") +
            ylab("meq/L") +
            ggtitle("Balace between cations and anions") +
            theme_economist() +
            scale_fill_discrete(
                c(
                    "#6794a7",
                    "#6794a7",
                    "#014d64",
                    "#76c0c1",
                    "#01a2d9",
                    "#7ad2f6",
                    "#00887d",
                    "#adadad",
                    "#7bd3f6",
                    "#7c260b",
                    "#ee8f71",
                    "#ee8f71",
                    "#6794a7"
                )
            ) +
            theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
                  legend.position = "bottom")
    })


    Conductivity <- reactive({

        Conductivity <- getConductivity(
            sodium = input$sodium,
            potassium = input$potassium,
            calcium = input$calcium,
            magnesium = input$magnesium,
            strontium = input$strontium,
            barium = input$barium,
            ammonium = input$ammonium,
            hydrogencarbonate = input$hydrogencarbonate,
            nitrate = input$nitrate,
            chlorine = input$chlorine,
            fluorine =input$fluorine,
            sulfate = input$sulfate,
            temperature = input$temperature,
            pH = input$pH
        )

    })

    output$Conductivity <- Conductivity
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The problem is in your function here: `sum(data$concentration[which(data$category == "cation")]) /  sum(data$concentration[which(data$category == "anion")])`. When the anion concentration summatory is zero, the division gives NaN, which makes your if statement fail. The app code for the plot works because you don't use `getConductivity`, instead you create the data by hand. You can either modify your function to work with zero anion concentration or require a minimal amount of anions in the app for this to work.

Comment: Done! Perfect! Thank you!